# SLDS classes not working

Tags: slds

I am new to this SLDS classes. The [button group](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/button-groups/#flavor-base-button-group-more-open) icon is not working. The UI renders perfectly but the event are not getting fired. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SLDS only provides the UI. As of now you have to write for the behavior on your own. There are some existing frameworks which is mostly used like [Lightning Dart](https://lightningdart.com/#/home) or [Appiphony](http://aljs.appiphony.com/#!/iconGroups)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SLDS in a Lightning Component, then you can leverage the [various components provided by the platform](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm) to do most of the work for you including dispatching to controller methods and in the case of the `lightning:` components also applying the correct CSS classes:

```
<div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
    <lightning:button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick="{! c.doSave }"/>
    <lightning:button label="Cancel" variant="neutral" onclick="{! c.doCancel }"/>
</div>
```